# includepdf not sizing correctly the page

Tags: pdf, pdfpages

I'm using pdfpages (in overleaf) to include a cover for my document. As you can see in the picture, it doesn't fit to the page. I've tried many options (noautoscale, fitpage, scale) but it is always the same, cropped upper-left corner and never fit on the bottom right.

Any help is more than welcome!

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{book}

\title{Perfect title}
\author{It's me, Mario}
\date{2024}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[noautoscale]{portada.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Hi @Mensch, I've added the code. Thanks!

Comment: Please make your code example complete (begins with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`) so others can play with it. You can find more about what makes a good minimal working example in [this Q&A](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Comment: Please run your example with `\includepdf{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}` and tell us if you experience the same problem as with `portada.pdf`. The file `example-image-a4-numbered.pdf` is from the `mwe` package and should be available in your TeX distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered thanks to @Katu's comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739159/inserting-a-pdf-file-in-latex).

Using *offset* option:

```
\includepdf[offset=25mm -25mm]{portada.pdf}
```

Comment: This is most likely an answer to another issue in your LaTeX code, but not an answer to your given MWE. Better double-check why you need this offset. Usually it should not be necessary.